# Let MPart listen to eventBroker event

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have an Eclipse E4 application. The application is currently activating all the MParts that are linked to a specific persective when its opens. Now I find out that opening a new perspective takes ages (about 20s). So I'm refactoring the code for speeding up opening perspectives.

I active them because otherwise the mParts are not listening to EventBroker events.
My code to activate the parts looks like:

```
public void makeAllActive(MPerspective perspective) {
        List<MPart> part = service.findElements(application, null, MPart.class, null);
        List<MPartStack> mainPartStack = service.findElements(application, "partstack.shared", MPartStack.class, null);

        if (!mainPartStack.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = part.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                List<MPart> children = service.findElements(mainPartStack.get(0), part.get(i).getElementId(),
                        MPart.class, null);

                if (!children.contains(part.get(i))) {
                    this.partService.activate(part.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also with the code when users switches multiple perspectives and comes back to the first one the selected part will not be on top of all the other parts. This is also not really user friendly.

Is there a way to activate all the parts that are in the perspective so that the parts can listen to eventBroker events?

Comment: Why do parts which are not active need to listen for events? This sounds like a design error.

Comment: Are some of the requirements the customer wants. All the data must be loaded so that if the user select a tab it does show its data insantly (without calling the backend server again).

Comment: A Part is a User Interface object it should be obtaining the data from some 'model' object which deals with non-UI events. In any case, I don't think there is any way to do what you ask. There is no instance of the MPart until it is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you want to open all the dialogs on application start. It is possible in theory, but will lead to the very unexpected things from the user perspective. In fact, your request is very similar, as you want to have all the MParts activated.

> All the data must be loaded so that if the user select a tab it does show its data insantly (without calling the backend server again)

So, you want to have all the data pre-fetched. This problem is not related with MPart activation. You need to create some service(s), that will execute all the backend calls for you. And then each MPart will just render the available results.